# Custom filter on text containing html

Tags: php, html

I want to do a custom filter by combining the strip_tags with the htmlspecialchars.

Let's say we have the following string: `<p>lorem ipsum <span>dolor sit amet</span></p>`.
I only want the `<p>` tag to be interpreted by the browser, and I want the `<span>` tag to be listed as plain text. 
Actually, my question is how can I show the html tags that don't belong to my strip_tags allowable_tags list, as plain text?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

So, if I properly understood you, you mean to keep `<p>` tag as HTML but inside the `<p></p>` escape any other HTML tags?

**In this case**, you have to filter the string `<p>lorem ipsum <span>dolor sit amet</span></p>`,
for example using `preg_match()`

let's **try** this **pattern** `^<p>(.*)<\/p>$`, **the function is** `preg_match('/^<p>(.*)<\/p>$/', '<p>lorem ipsum <span>dolor sit amet</span></p>', $match)`

**See the reference http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php**

$match will return an array - every () in pattern means match you want to get.

```
Array
(
    [0] => <p>lorem ipsum <span>dolor sit amet</span></p>
    [1] => lorem ipsum <span>dolor sit amet</span>
)
```

**And $match[1] is the right thing you can work with!**

So, finally you can `htmlspecialchars($match[1])`. Result is, that whatever content in `<p></p`> will be easily **escaped**

Comment: No, I don't want to do strip_tags the content between the `<p></p>` tag. I want to show all the html tags between the `<p></p>` as plain text. So, the `<span>` tag should be listed plain, not interpreted.

Comment: Ooops, @JeremiahWinsley you're right. Answer corrected, thank you!

Comment: @IlieGurzun simple replace with htmlspecialchars like in the corrected answer